# how to make a html element respond differently to single and double click?

Tags: javascript, mouse, onclick

Normally when double-clicking single clicks are called. Is there any method to surpass doing onclick and wait if second click comes in short time ?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

Use the `ondblclick` event for things that should only happen on double click.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.ondblclick

Note that the onClick event handler will fire even on a double click. If that behavior is undesired you can set the event to happen on a timer and then cancel that timer from within the double click event handler.

Answer (score 1):

**No.** (ish)

Unlike some OS or devices that wait to process the `click` handler until the `dblclick` delay has passed, you will get two `click` events when you double-click. See this test for example: http://jsfiddle.net/S53mn/

The only way to work around this is to delay your click handler by the amount of a double-click delay and cancel your click handler if a double-click is detected. This is

1. **hard**, because the double-click delay varies from OS-to-OS and may be based on user settings, and
2. **annoying** because *(if you account for very long possible double-click timers)* there will be a very noticeable lag between when the user performs a single click and when you start processing it.